# Video displays on views results but not on node

Tags: views

I created a view that renders a list of video descriptions like title, speakers, speaker picture and a View Video link. The title and View Video link the direct user to the video page. But, the video does not render on that page. Instead, only the title of the video in form of a link renders.

Field Formatter is set to Render file and View Mode set to Default. I've also tried Full content. Also, I created a template using

```
render($content['field_webinar_video']);
```

But in that case, it only renders the title/link as well. How do I get the video to render?

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I found that I needed to change the display of the field within the content type. Content Type > Manage Display. For the video field, I changed the format to Render file. It was previously set to Generic file.